# How to check multiple services on different servers in powershell scripting?

Tags: powershell

I have 3 servers

> server a, server b, server c

I want to check 3 services,

> service = serva, servb, servc
>
> server a contains serva and servb
>
> server b contains servb and serv c
>
> server c contains servc only

I already seen a script for checking different services on different servers but i cannot think of a way to edit it to fit to my needs. Can anyone help me please on how to check multiple servies (some are the same) in different servers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way to do this:

```
$services = @( @{Computername="ServerA"; ServiceName="ServiceA"},
    @{Computername="ServerA"; ServiceName="ServiceB"},
    @{Computername="ServerB"; ServiceName="ServiceB"},
    @{Computername="ServerB"; ServiceName="ServiceC"},
    @{Computername="ServerC"; ServiceName="ServiceC"}
)

$services | %{Get-Service -Computername $_.Computername -ServiceName $_.ServiceName}

# Because I used a hashtable with full parameter names for $services, I can do this trick
$services | %{Get-Service @_ }
```

Now I did a lot of advanced stuff there. We can make this smpler by putting your data in a CSV file. Just use ComputerName and ServiceName as the columns to fit this example. Just have one server and one service on each line.

```
$services = Import-CSV servicelist.txt
$services | %{Get-Service -Computername $_.Computername -ServiceName $_.ServiceName}
```

The default output may not show the computer name so it would be a good idea to pipe it to a `Select-Object MachineName, Name, Status`.

Comment: At first the array of hashtables seemed clunky and awkward, but after a little thought I have to admit this is an extremely elegant answer to the question. Nicely done kevmar.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer kevmar and thanks Matt for editing my question. Kevmar i will try this today, I will keep you posted thanks for the prompt answer again.